# how to unit test an app that requries a user to log in a different site

Tags: unit-testing, authentication

So I'm making a small application that requires the user to log into spotify's portal to get the auth token for their api calls. I was just curious how is this handled on a unit test level where typically I don't have access to a browser?

Answer (score 0):

As far as unit tests are concerned, they should use mock an external application call so that tests run fast independently of external system because of network latency and availability issues.
You can have a mock that you can expect to return successful response/errors against your unit tests.